# W2k8, Sybase Driver, Permissions

Tags: windows, iis, .net

Trying to get a .net (32bit) app running on a Windows 2008 server.  My experience in the Windows world is quite limited...

Is this related to the Full/Medium trust settings?  Windows error logging is pure nonsense :(((

Have been Googling for quite some time.  Appreciate your feedback!

Seeing the following error:

```
  Required permissions cannot be acquired.
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

 Exception Details: System.Security.Policy.PolicyException: Required permissions cannot be acquired.

 Source Error:

 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

 Stack Trace:

 [PolicyException: Required permissions cannot be acquired.]
    System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Boolean checkExecutionPermission) +7606467
    System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Int32& securitySpecialFlags, Boolean checkExecutionPermission) +57

 [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Sybase.Data.AseClient, Version=1.155.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=26e0f1529304f4a7' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)]
    System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
    System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +43
    System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +127
    System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +142
    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

 [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Sybase.Data.AseClient, Version=1.155.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=26e0f1529304f4a7' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)]
    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +203
         System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +105
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
    System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory vdir) +163
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +53
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +175
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +86
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +261
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +101
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +126
    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +62
    System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +33
    System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path) +37
    System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +307
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155




Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4959; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955
```

Comment: would you think this article is relevant?  http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1028614

Comment: http://forum.galleryserverpro.com/yaf_postst855_error-required-permissions-cannot-be-acquired.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The site is on a NAS... so naturally windows does funny things... Solution:

Drive:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -m -ag 1 -url "file:////\computername\sharename*" FullTrust -exclusive on

per

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=320268

Comment: Also, you may wish to configure 32 bit vs 64 bit ODBC Sybase... driver